# What does "inquiry" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

From [here](https://edition.cnn.com/travel/article/swiss-gold-bars-intl-scli/index.html):

> In a bulletin dated June 2, officials said the owner has five years to make a claim for the treasure.

> A spokesperson for the prosecutor's office told CNN that several **inquiries** had been made about the gold and were being checked. Not details about the nature of the checks were given.

At first I thought an **inquiry** meant "a claim for the treasure" in the same way it is mentioned in previous paragraph. As if a lot of people claimed the treasure and these claims "were being checked" (for truthness, as the sentence says).

But it turned out that most definitions I found for **inquiry** refers to "a claim" but "for information" only (instead of an object, a thing), or an "investigation". As if who made the inquiry was the police (not the people).

If **inquiry** here means simply "investigation", what would "an investigation being checked" mean?

Thanks!

Comment: It means the *answers* to the inquiries were being checked. *"How does he like his food prepared?" "I don't know, but thank you for the inquiry. Let me check [with him] and get back to you."*

Comment: It's somewhat ambiguous.  The context may imply a special meaning for "inquiry", but you'd have to be familiar with prosecutors' lingo to know.

Comment: Thanks @HotLicks - But which way would you interpret it? *(a)* "The police started several inquiries which in turn revealed some possible owners of the gold bars (and police is now checking (=further analysing) these possibilities)" **or** *(b)* "Several people made inquiries (special use meaning for "claims") about the ownership of the gold bars"?

Comment: @RicardoBaptista - Not needing to interpret it, I wouldn't.

Comment: Thanks @JasonBassford. Like if after the police inquired several people now they are validating those people's answers to find the most likely owner of the gold bars?

Comment: @RicardoBaptista It's not clear if the inquires came from people in general (or, if so, to whom the questions were asked) or from the prosecutor's office itself. Since it's *had been* ***made***, it's almost certainly in the *asked about* sense. If it were *had been* ***started***, then it would be in the *official investigation* sense. It's also unlikely (although not impossible) that a prosecutor's office would start multiple investigations into the same thing. It would normally be a single investigation, smaller or larger in scope as appropriate.